# Disable underline for hyperlinkcolumn in radgrid

Tags: asp.net

I'm using RadGrid in my project.
I'have gridhyperlinkcolumn in my grid and its working  well but
I want to disable the underline for hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

Set the Css on the gridhyperlinkColumn to include "text-decoration:none;"

Comment: it will work if your css is applied to the correct Element - you need to view the source of the outputted columns and ensure you apply the css correctly... eg: if html = <td class="columnCssClass"><a href="...">text not underlined</a></td> then the css needs to be .columnCssClass a {text-decoration:none;}

Comment: Also, remember that css is "Cascading" - so this declaration needs to be after any css applied by the radGrid itself...